# display:none; starting at a certain number?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't know how to say it in CSS. If I for example have a div class with 10 imgs but I only want the first three to be shown. I know that there's something like

```
.divclass:nth-of-type(n) {
    display:none;
}
```

But I don't want to paste this code seven times and change the `n`. I want it to say something like "don't display any image after the first three" so that it will still only show the first three after I add 11, 12, 13, 14, ... images.

Thank you!

Comment: hide them all, then just create css to show the first three. Then regardless of how many you enter you always get the desired result

Comment: that's a nice idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```css
img:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/101x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/102x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/103x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/104x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/105x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/106x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/107x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/108x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/109x100"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/110x100"/>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**
`n` is a count starting with `0`. So the first rule would be `(0 + 4 = 4) => img:nth-of-type(4)`, the second rule would be `(1 + 4 = 5) => img:nth-of-type(5)` and so on.

Comment: And do you maybe know where to add ':before' / ':after' if you use this code?